# Selecting all values from User Defined Type in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, user-defined-types

I've got a user defined type in my code, `phrase_context_typ`. I call a `function`, `phrase_context`, which returns an instance of `phrase_context_typ`.

The user defined type is defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type phrase_context_typ AS OBJECT (
    context   VARCHAR2(13),
    parent_id NUMBER(10) 
)
```

I have a `VIEW` which contains `CONTEXT` and `PARENT_ID` columns. I want to select from this `VIEW` based on the values present in the `phrase_context_typ` instance.

I am able to do this in the following manner:

```
select distinct(col)
    from my_view v
    where v.parent_id = PHRASE_CONTEXT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?).parent_id 
          and
          v.context = PHRASE_CONTEXT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?).context
```

This works but is it possible to do the equivalent with **only one call** to the `phrase_context` `function`? I want to only call the `function` once not only for elegance but also because there are further `select` statements within the `function` so efficiency will be compromised by calling it *n* times.

I suppose what I'm asking is that if something like the following can be achieved in Oracle SQL, i.e. effectively flattening a user defined type instance into a row:

```
select PHRASE_CONTEXT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?).* from dual;
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subquery factoring will do it:

```
with data as (select phrase_context (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) obj from dual)
select distinct(col)
    from my_view v, data d
    where v.parent_id = d.obj.parent_id
          and 
          v.context = d.obj.context
```